# Do incoming LAN UDP packets create an entry containing senders MAC in receivers ARP table in Linux?

Tags: linux, udp, arp

When Linux receives a UDP packet originating from a sender having a LAN source IP, will Linux put the source MAC address of this packet along the source IP address into the ARP cache table?

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: I'm about to try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried Linux 4.9 and the answer in this case is **no**. I crafted an UDP packet with an artificial IP address and MAC address combo, which was received by the Linux-under-Test and displayed correctly by *netcat*. No ARP entry was created (also no incomplete one) and Linux did not send any ARP request regarding the artificial IP address.